# Visual Studio - Wrong watch value

Tags: c#, arrays, debugging, visual-studio-2012, watch

While debugging in Visual Studio 2012, I came across a situation where I believe that watch had been displaying a wrong value.

`counts[3][0]` is an integer array that had just been created. (Length of the array is 96). All values in that array are zero, as expected, *except* from  `counts[3][0][87]` which equals to 2.

The bug was still present after restarting my program many times, but it disappeared after restarting Visual Studio.

Is this a documented bug?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: There is a possibility that it could be a bug in .NET Framework as well. Did you check the result of a calculation that uses counts[3][0][87]?

Comment: Might probably be another thread accessing the `counts` array at the same time?

Comment: @gehho: No, everything is in a single thread.